# Install php-clamav on cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel, php-extension

I'm trying to compile and install `php-clamav` on a CentOS 6 cPanel system. cPanel is the one who installs ClamAV, so it's not at it's default path.

ClamAV is located at: `/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin`

And the libs are at: `/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64`

When installing I get this:

```
checking for clamav support... yes, shared
checking for clamav files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the clamav distribution
```

This is the command I've used as per the documentation:

```
./configure --with-clamav
```

I even tried telling it where to find the libs:

```
./configure --with-clamav --with-libdir=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib64
```

Same error. I know ClamAV is installed and working because if I run `/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/clamscan` it runs fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try looking over here for help with the default path: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28383931/problem-configuring-clamav-with-php-clamav.html